# GET method in API call to preserve headers

Tags: api, asp.net-core, response-headers

I have an asp.net core application and I want the request headers to be preserved in the response.
I have 3 headers on the request in postman,

```
Authorization: "Bearer xxxxx"
azet-Accept: application/json"
azet-UseLatestversion: true
```

Here is what I have setup in configure method,

```
app.Use(
        async (context, next) =>
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'");
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Referrer-Policy", "no-referrer");
            context.Response.Headers.Add(
                "Feature-Policy",
                "accelerometer 'none'; camera 'none'; geolocation 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; microphone 'none'; payment 'none'; usb 'none'");
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
            await next();
        });

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(
        endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

I want the headers like azet-UseLatestversion to be returned in the response

Any ideas?

Thanks

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{apiPath}/{*requestUri}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(string apiPath, string requestUri = "")
{
    var queryString = this.Request.QueryString.Value;

    var headers = this.Request
        .Headers
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value.FirstOrDefault());

    var response = await this.proxy.GetAsync(
                apiPath, requestUri, queryString, headers, this.GetUserScopes());

    this.logger.LogInformation(
                $"GET statement received from {apiPath} {requestUri} {queryString} {DateTime.Now}.");

    var test = response.Content;

    if (response.HttpStatus != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        this.logger.LogError($"{apiPath} {requestUri} {queryString} {response.HttpStatus}: {response.Content}");

        return this.StatusCode((int)response.HttpStatus, ErrorResponse.GetDefaultMessageForStatusCode((int)response.HttpStatus));
    }
     return this.Content(response.Content?.ToString(), response.ContentType);
 }
```

Comment: Not sure what is your requirement,because what you did in middleware could work well to return customed header in response.Did you want to auto get the request header and save it to the response?

Answer (score 0):

> I want the request headers to be preserved in the response

Here is a working demo:

```
app.Use(
    async (context, next) =>
    {
        foreach (var header in context.Request.Headers)
        {
            if(!header.Key.Contains(":"))
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value.ToString());
            }
        }           
        await next();
    });
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: That worked. Thanks!!! My response however has some custom headers added but they are not displayed in postman.This is my return statement,  "return this.Content(response.Content?.ToString(), response.ContentType);" How can I display the custom headers in postman?

Comment: What is your `response`?Could you please share more code?It seems you call another api and get the response?